# Invoking a custom IntelliJ IDEA Annotator programmatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, intellij-plugin

I have been working on a plugin that inspects annotations on instance fields, looks up one of their attribute values and checks if that attribute value exists in a data source (I load the relevant data in an `AnAction` which updates my singleton `DataSource` instance).

When the user first loads up the IDE, there is no connection established. Invoking the custom action loads the values, but since my `Annotator` has already done its job, my fields do not pick up the change and are incorrectly marked with an error marker. Altering the specific attribute value inside the annotation then forces the `Annotator` to run again and the change is finally picked up.

What is the recommended way of invoking an Annotator programmatically? Specifically I'd like to do this within `AnAction` when values are loaded successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for this is to force rehighlighting of the files using `DaemonCodeAnalyzer.getInstance().restart()`.